# Asus PCE-N53 11n N600 PCI-E Adapter on 3.x kernel

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express

## Problem

ASUS PCE-N53 wireless NIC doesn't work for latest versions of the linux kernel. How do I get it working on my system?

Comment: You might want to split this up into a question, and an answer. We arn't a forum, so we're cool with you getting credit twice ;).

Comment: FYI: http://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Installing Driver for Linux 3.x Kernel

ASUS provides Linux drivers from their website, but it mentions that the driver supports "Linux Kernel 2.6.x", so it won't work without a some modifications to the driver code.

Fortunately, an [archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1223141) mentions similar problems and one user was able to create a patch for kernel 3.8.x that seems to work with kernel 3.11.x.

Here's how I got it working:

### Prerequisites

#### Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

#### Arch:

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel linux-headers
```

### Steps:

#### 1. Download the driver from the [ASUS website](http://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEN53)

The download can be found under "Support > Drivers & Tools".

#### 2. Unzip the contents of the downloaded file

cd into the new directory

#### 3. Patch

The arch forum mentions a 3.8 patch file that needs to be downloaded.

1. Download `rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch` to the current directory.
2. `tar -xvf {driver_source.tar.gz}`
3. `cd` into the directory created in previous step
4. `patch -p1 < ../rt5592sta_fix_64bit_3.8.patch`

#### 4. Compile

**NOTE**: You will need to use sudo for it to compile properly.

```
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5592sta
```

#### 5. Enjoy

If all is well, you should now have a working card.

Comment: I have published patched source code with instructions on [GitHub](https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux). Or [directly download it](https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux/archive/v1.0.zip).